# What module do I turn off to hide or remove the voting widget in Drupal Commons?

Tags: 7, rating

Our client wants this voting widget turned off? At worst, I could hide with CSS but I'd like to turn this off. What module produces this? Should I remove/hide a field from the content type?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I found it was the [Rate](https://drupal.org/project/Rate) module.